# Closed questions shown in Review

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review

The message below the Review stat's in the right hand side says

```
Hiding reviewed and closed posts
```

But, I see a closed post on `first-answers` review page that is Closed.

[image]

Probably, the filter is not correctly set here?

#### Another Thought

Is the above message only for the questions? Can answers to closed question still appear in review process ?

Comment: That's confusing... I always thought it referred to the stats above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have rolled out a new review system which shouldn't include closed posts.